# Running multiple environment with same Python code from separate command prompts

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I have a Python program which resides on say `D:\Pycharmprojects\myProj\x.py`

I have 3 separate directories A, B, C which represent 3 different environments with their specific `data.json` which `x.py` reads and executes.

Currently each time I want to run the `x.py` on those environments I open 3 different command prompts and navigate to each directory A, B, C
then I run on each: `python D:\PycharmProjects\myProj\x.py`

Is there a better way or faster way to launch 3 different command prompts and run the program? I do want the tests to run on diff command prompts so I can  see stdOuts for each and can find out if three was an exception or ...

Comment: Hm... didn't know there's a Python version for DOS...

Comment: The `start` command defaults to creating a new console and has a `/d` option to set the working directory. You can combine it with `cmd /k` to run the script. The shell remains attached to the console after Python exits, so the console window isn't immediately destroyed. For example, `start "Environment A" /d "path\to\A" cmd /k python D:\PycharmProjects\myProj\x.py`. You can start all 3 from a batch script.

Comment: Thanks this shows only one environment A, start "Environment A" /d "path\to\A" cmd /k python D:\PycharmProjects\myProj\x.py   what is the command to execute all 3 env. A, B, C with one command?

Comment: Would it be?  start "Environment A" /d "path\to\A" "Environment B" /d "path\to\B" "Environment C" /d "path\to\C" cmd /k python D:\PycharmProjects\myProj\x.py

Comment: Are you using any environment management? i.e `conda`,`pipenv` or `virtualenv`